# Why do I keep getting this Syntax Error in BigQuery

Tags: sql, syntax, google-bigquery, syntax-error

I keep getting this syntax error:
Syntax error: SELECT list must not be empty at [2:3]

on my SQL query:
Select
FROM 'tfdalissabuck.assessment_01.experiment'
WHERE experiment_cohort = 'treatment' AND   minutes_listening_during_experiment > '60'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need something between `SELECT` AND `FROM`, a single or multiple column names.
Also I believe you are using single quotes around the table name, you should be using a tick mark, and if minutes_listening_during_experiment is an integer you can remove the quotes around it

```
SELECT *
FROM `tfdalissabuck.assessment_01.experiment`
WHERE experiment_cohort = 'treatment' 
AND minutes_listening_during_experiment > 60
```